# MS Access PIVOT with User Defined Field

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

Any of you good souls please help!!

I need to query the source table shown in the below. (NULL are blank fields)

```
UNUM Ticket Overflow 
1    135    NULL
1    136    NULL
1    137    NULL
1    138    NULL
1    NULL   2b
2    135    NULL
2    136    NULL
2    137    NULL
3    135    NULL
3    136    NULL
3    137    NULL
3    138    NULL
3    139    NULL
3    140    NULL
3    NULL   66a
4    NULL   12a
5    NULL   14a
```

I need to generate the output as shown below.

```
UserNum Ticket1 Ticket2 Ticket3 Ticket4 Ticket5 Ticket6 Ticket7 Ticket8 Ticket9 Overflow
1       135     136     137     138     Null     Null   Null    Null    Null    2b
2       135     136     137     Null    Null     Null   Null    Null    Null    Null      
3       135     136     137     138     139      140    Null    Null    Null    66a   
4       Null    Null    Null    Null    Null     Null   Null    Null    Null    12a       
5       Null    Null    Null    Null    Null     Null   Null    Null    Null    14a
```

1. The source table has multiple tickets assigned to user. There are always maximum of 9 tickets.
2. The user either has a ticket or an overflow but here can be only overflow per user.

I am having issue pivoting the data in Ticket column to pre-defined field names like Ticket1, Ticket2...

Comment: What logic are you using to assign a value for Ticket1, etc.? Be aware, though, that you shouldn't rely upon the order that Access stores the values in. Access makes no guarantees about this order. To achieve this you would need to create an additional numbered, or date-stamped, column in the table. But if you know which Ticket number each value applies to then these ticket number should be stored in the table.

Answer (score 0):

(For this answer I've used [TicketJournal] as the name of the source table.)

First we need to prepare the data for the crosstab (pivot). We can accomplish that by aggregating over an unequal self-join on the source table to generate the "Tickets" rows, and then UNION-ing that with a simple SELECT on the source table for the "Overflows"

```sql
    SELECT 
        UNUM AS UserNum, 
        CStr(Ticket) AS Item, 
        "Ticket" & COUNT(Ticket) AS Destination
    FROM
        (
            SELECT tj1.UNUM, tj1.Ticket 
            FROM 
                TicketJournal tj1 
                INNER JOIN 
                TicketJournal tj2 
                    ON tj1.UNUM=tj2.UNUM 
                        AND tj1.Ticket>=tj2.Ticket
        )
    GROUP BY UNUM, Ticket
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        UNUM AS UserNum,
        Overflow AS Item,
        "Overflow" AS Destination
    FROM TicketJournal
    WHERE Overflow IS NOT NULL
```

Save that query in Access as [TicketCrosstabSource] and then run it to verify that it returns

```
UserNum  Item  Destination
-------  ----  -----------
      1  135   Ticket1    
      1  136   Ticket2    
      1  137   Ticket3    
      1  138   Ticket4    
      2  135   Ticket1    
      2  136   Ticket2    
      2  137   Ticket3    
      3  135   Ticket1    
      3  136   Ticket2    
      3  137   Ticket3    
      3  138   Ticket4    
      3  139   Ticket5    
      3  140   Ticket6    
      1  2b    Overflow   
      3  66a   Overflow   
      4  12a   Overflow   
      5  14a   Overflow
```

Now we can just do a crosstab query against the [TicketCrosstabSource] query...

```sql
TRANSFORM First(TicketCrosstabSource.[Item]) AS FirstOfItem
SELECT TicketCrosstabSource.[UserNum]
FROM TicketCrosstabSource
GROUP BY TicketCrosstabSource.[UserNum]
PIVOT TicketCrosstabSource.[Destination] In ("Ticket1","Ticket2","Ticket3","Ticket4","Ticket5","Ticket6","Ticket7","Ticket8","Ticket9","Overflow");
```

...which returns

```
UserNum  Ticket1  Ticket2  Ticket3  Ticket4  Ticket5  Ticket6  Ticket7  Ticket8  Ticket9  Overflow
-------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  --------
      1  135      136      137      138                                                   2b      
      2  135      136      137                                                                    
      3  135      136      137      138      139      140                                 66a     
      4                                                                                   12a     
      5                                                                                   14a
```